# Accessing an array inside an array

Tags: arrays, scala, any

I am new to coding in scala and I am curious about something and it has been hard to find an answer for online. I have this array that takes multiple arguments of different types (:Any)

`val arguments= Array("Monday",10,20,Array("test","test2"), if(4 == 4){ "true"})`

I iterated and printed the content inside of it. Everything prints properly except the Array at index 3. I get the object memory address I believe, which is understandable-- same thing with Java would happen. But I am curious, how would you access it?

I tried saving the value of arguments(3) in an array `(val arr:Array[String] = arguments(3))` but it didn't work because there is a type mismatch `(any != Array[String])`

Any tips? It might be a gap in my understanding of functional programming.

Comment: Having an **Array** is a bad practice, having an **Any** is another bad practice. Having both is serious flag of a bad design, the best way to solve this is taking a step back and redesign your solution to avoid this.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for your feedback! I was just trying to play around, so it's not a real solution to a problem, but I am wondering how to develop better practice in scala? Do you have suggestions for some resources?

Comment: Are you following some resources for learning the language? **Scala** is a mix between OOP and FP as such, learning it is more complex than just learning syntax and best practices, you have to learn a different way to think and solve problems.

Comment: I see. I have background in Java and used other OOP languages but never FP. I have a project in my job that requires me to write code in Scala so I was just following tutorials online and working on building projects I have written in Java before in Scala to get up to speed. My learning approach might be flawed though.

Comment: I would recommend you to take any formal course or book that does a good introduction of the language step by step. [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/?_ga=2.247794951.1402996065.1596044249-1166759874.1581082605) you can find a list with various resources.

Answer (score 0):

What you are iterating through is an `Array[Any]`, so you are able to perform functions that are available to an `Any` type. You can access the items in your array using pattern matching, which uses the `unapply` methods under the hood to see if it can turn your `Any` into something more specific:

```scala
  val arguments= Array("Monday",10,20,Array("test","test2"), if(4 == 4){ "true"})

  arguments foreach { arg =>
    arg match {
      case a:Array[String] => println(s"This is the array: ${a.mkString(",")}, and I can do array functions ${a.contains("test")}")
      case _ => println(s"Otherwise I have this: $arg")
    }
  }
//  stdout:
//  Otherwise I have this: Monday
//  Otherwise I have this: 10
//  Otherwise I have this: 20
//  This is the array: test,test2, and I can do array functions true
//  Otherwise I have this: true
```

Comment: Note that the `Array[String]` check is actually unsafe. The string part is a lie _(and the compiler warns you about that)_ you actually can only check if it is an array.

Comment: Thank you, I just learned about pattern matching and this was helpful.

Comment: Why is the case that if I did ${a.toString} I get the memory address, but if I did ${a.mkString} I get the content of the array?

Comment: @Haytham because they are two different methods? Is like asking why `5 + 3` gives `8` and `5 - 3` gives `2` - `mkString` as the name suggests creates a string from the collection. Most collections implement their `toString` in terms of `mkString`, this is not the case of **Arrays** because those are not really a collection but a primitive of the **JVM**.